# Knitting returns parse error

Tags: r, rstudio

In attempting to knit a PDF. I'm calling a script that should return two ggplots by calling the chunk:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}

read_chunk('Script.R')

```r
````

But receive the error

```
processing file: Preview-24a46368403c.Rmd

 Quitting from lines 9-12 (Preview-24a46368403c.Rmd)  Error in
 parse(text = x, srcfile = src) :    attempt to use zero-length
 variable name Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> parse_all ->
 parse_all.character -> parse Execution halted
```

The script on its own runs and returns the two plots, but won't return them when knitted.

Similarly attempted to use `source()`
But got a similar error

```
 Quitting from lines 7-10 (Preview-24a459ca4c1.Rmd)  Error in
 file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :    cannot open the
 connection Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible
 -> eval -> eval -> source -> file Execution halted
```

Answer (score 10):

While this does not appear to be a solution for you, this exact same error message appears if the chunk is not ended properly.

I experienced this error and traced it to ending chunk with `` instead of ```. Correcting the syntax of the chunk solved the problem I experienced with the same error message as you.

Comment: I guess this is the most common cause of this error. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that knitr is running from the directory you think it is? It appears that it is failing to find the file.

- use an absolute path, if that fixes it, you've found your problem
- once you've done that, you can use `opts_knit$set(root.dir = "...")` -- don't use `setwd(.)` if you want it (the cwd) to be maintained.

Knitr's default is the directory of the `.Rmd` file itself.

Comment: I added the absolute path here:
`source("c:/users/me/documents/Script.R")
opts_knit$set(root.dir = "c:/users/me/documents/")` But I'm still getting 
`Quitting from lines 7-11 (Preview-24a43ec36ef0.Rmd) 
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... write.csv -> eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> write.table -> file
Execution halted1`

Comment: Got it. Have you tried just directly copying in the contents of Script.R into the .Rmd file? If you have, and that works, then it certainly a problem with what read_chunk expects and what you're passing, but in order to debug that, we need the contents of Script.R

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the "r" at the end of the triple backquotes demarcating your code chunk. There should be nothing after the triple backquotes, but I think the problem is specifically that the letter is "r".

The issue stems from the fact that R markdown processes backquoted statements starting with `r` as [inline code](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-4.html), meaning it actually runs whatever is between the backquotes.

I had similar issues writing a problem set in an Rmd with this statement, which had backquoted text intended to be monospace but not run as inline code:

> Use `sapply` or `map` to calculate the probability of a failure rate over `r <- seq(.05, .5, .025)`.

When I knit the document, I got opaque error messages saying I had an improper assignment using `<-`. It was because instead of just displaying the backquoted statement in monospace, `r <- seq(.05, .5, .025)` was actually processed as R inline code of `<- seq(.05, .5, .025)`...thus the improper assignment error. I fixed my error by changing the variable name from `r` to `rate`.

The actual text of the error message in your question might refer to whatever follows your code chunk, as the knitting process is probably trying to run that as code. In this case, just removing that stray `r` at the end of the code chunk should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following similar syntax, I had the same exact issue but got it fixed:

````
    ```{r views}
bank.df <- read.csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Banks.csv", header = TRUE) #load data
dim(bank.df) # to find dimension of data frame
head(bank.df) # show first six rows
```
````

the ``` has to be in the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was that I finished the code with four comas, not three . Check this and If you finished with four comas too, try to delete one of them.